# 2 forms in the same page in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to know if there is a way to display 2 form in a same page, the reason is that I want have a search field in a form that when this make submit, the form2 display the list of data, in the form2 there is a textfield when you can select items for the list and set a comment on for the selected items so when form2 make submit save information about every selected item.

So there is way?

Thanks.

Comment: You can have multiple forms in same page if they are different forms (form IDs). Putting same form id form in same page works, but if the user makes a mistake, they will see the error field highlighted in both forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of two forms you can have one form with two submit buttons which can have separate submit functions